# Where do I store the application's resource

Tags: android, android-resources

Our application gets images from network. And need to save it locally.

Where should I store it? In internal storage in files, in SQLite db in Blob field or in the external storage?

Internal storage space on old devices is very low, so should i check free space and that chose place to store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is well documented in Android Developers: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

As you're saying, old devices can have low free space and if you're ok with your files being accessible from a file manager then it is preferred to check if external storage exists and save it there.

EDIT:
Check if external storage is present:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So.. For example, i saved some images in internal storage, after that there is no free space. So i should save new images in external storage...This fragmentation of data seems bad.

Comment: No, if there is an external storage, always save there. If users do have an external storage they more than likely want all the extra data there, if however it is sensitive data that you do not want to give them easy access to it's wiser to save in internal storage. Editing my answer with check for external storage.